# Integrate grid view scroll with other fragments

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing an instagram look-alike app.

I need to know how can I achieve the following:

1. When we start scrolling the grid view upwards it should gradually
   increase height (achieving full screen) while the above  Relative
   Layout will start to disappear?
2. When we start scrolling downwards it should return to
   its original state (when we reach the first row of images) and make the relative layout above reappear?

[image]

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0):

"Integration" is difficult. To get instagram behaviour I suggest you to use `RecyclerView` with a header. So you gonna have 2 view types: a header (`RelativeLayout`) and images. `HeaderGridView` is a good implementation with `GridView`. Google for "header GridView/RecyclerView".